# Concatenating a char with an int and a string does odd things

Tags: c#, .net

I was coding and needed to build up a file name.  I wanted to separate the parts of the file names by an _.

I figured that since I only wanted to add on char in I could use `'_'`.

```
int id = 125;

string testWithChar = id + '_' + "Something";
Console.WriteLine(testWithChar);
```

But when I do I get this:

> 220Something

Kind of odd.

But if I do it right:

```
int id = 125;

string testWithString = id + "_" + "Something";
Console.WriteLine(testWithString);
```

I get the expected output:

> 125_Something

**But I am curious.  What is really happening in the first one to give me a different number?**

Comment: Because  `id + '_' ` is evaluated first. you can change priority like `id + ('_' + "Something")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, C# is considering the char as it's unicode value, and thus the addition between them does not add strings, but integers.
`_` in ascii is 95, and thus

```
int id = 125;

string testWithChar = id + '_' + "Something";
```

is the equivallent of:

```
string testWithChar = 125 + 95 + "Something";
```

In contrast, when you add `"_"`, the addition is done between a string and an integer - and the operator just appends the string to it.

Comment: @Marc That's right. regardless, the default operator for addition between characters and integers adds them together, and `_` is contained in ascii as well. :) editted

Answer (score 1):

The int value of a `char` is its place in the ASCII table. `'_'` is at place 95

Answer (score 1):

When you add an integer to another numeric type, you end up with the result of the addition, rather than the concatenation. In this case, char is a numeric value, so 125 + 95 (value of '_') concatenated with your string gives you 220_Something.

I'd create the string as string.Format("{0}_{1}", id, "Something") instead, particularly as your final string gets more complicated.

Comment: Check out your math on the 125+90 part. ;)

Comment: Yeah, caught that just after I posted ;)

Comment: Plused for adding the `string.Format()`. Forgot about it completely.

Answer (score 0):

The int value is replaced with its ASCII value of 95.
Using string formatting is the most safe way:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}_Something", id);
```